# Set argparse optional value if other optional value is set

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to create the following situation in argparse.

**`--bar` must be true if `--foo` is true.**

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--bar', action='store_true', default=False)
```

So then:

```
% my_prog   => args.foo is False, args.bar is False
% my_prog --bar => args.foo is False. args.bar is True
% my_prog --foo => args.foo is True, args.bar is True
```

Can I do this within argparse, or do I need to test `args.foo` and set `args.bar` accordingly?  That doesn't seem right. I thought there was a way to associate a argument with a function that would do the check.

Comment: `argparse` doesn't have any builtin tools for this.  While it's possible to write custom action classes to do this kind of checking, the logic is a lot easier if done after parsing.

Comment: I'd argue that your options are perhaps new ones which represent what you describe on the right side rather than the current ones (`--foo` and `--bar`)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way for argparse to do it, but you can do it in a single line:

```
args.bar |= args.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it after parsing makes sense. I mean it's not really part of parsing itself. You would just write something like "--foo implies --bar" in the help text and in the code,

```
if args.foo:
    args.bar = True
```